# OneToOne mapping with NHibernate and Breeze

Tags: breeze

Is it possible to make that [kind of mapping](http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one) work with breeze and NHibernate:

```
public class PeopleMap: BaseMapping<People>
{
    public PeopleMap()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.FirstName);
        this.Property(x => x.LastName);
    }
}
public class PersonMap : JoinedSubclassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        this.Key(p=>p.Column("ID"));
        this.Property(x => x.FirstName);
        this.Property(x => x.LastName);
        this.Property(x => x.InfoId, map =>
            {
                map.Insert(false);
                map.Update(false);
            }
            );
        this.ManyToOne(x => x.Info, map =>
        {
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            map.Column("InfoId");
        });
    }
public class PersonInfoMap : BaseMapping<PersonInfo>
{
    public PersonInfoMap()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Extra);
        this.OneToOne(x => x.Person, map =>
        {
            map.Constrained(true);
            map.PropertyReference(p => p.Info);
        });
    }
}
```

There is a table per subclass inheritance between people and person. The goal is to make a one to one association between person and personinfo. The mapping works fine in NHibernate. The metadata are generated and queries can be done. The only problem is I can't do a save.

```
var d = breezeService.manager.createEntity('Person',
      {
          FirstName: 'Laurent',
          LastName: 'Nullens'
      });

    var l = breezeService.manager.createEntity('PersonInfo',
        {
            Extra: 'First data',
            Person: d
        });

    d.Info = l;
```

The result is an exception because the Person entity is saved before the PersonInfo(foreign key exception). I saw in the samples a one to one with Order and InternationlOrder but in that sample both entities share the same primary key.

Is it possbile or is there any workaround like in the Order/InternationalOrder sample?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the **[breezjs NHibernate sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/NorthBreeze)**?

Please do ... and then report back if you can't find what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried the samples but it does not work as expected(trying to expand IntenationalOrder does not work oob). I'll do a working sample from yours at home because I think we're hitting an edge case(related to the inheritance and the one-to-one). Thanks

Comment: Thank you! We look forward to your repro.